# Is Apple Push Notification Service is Country specific?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

In my application i have implemented the APNs. 
currently, I am using application from India and sending a push notification in United kingdom where someone is using my application,but the problem is he is not receiving the notification.

If i am sending push notification to someone who is in india then he is receiving it.

I wanted to know that, Is the APNs is country specific service, If it is not country specific then what should i do to overcome this issue.
Thankyou very much !!!!

Comment: You should contact apple directly for this

Comment: I got the exactly same issue, how did you fix it finally

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered. However if your service sending the push notifications seems to be working then you can debug on the following lines:

1. The user may have disabled the push notifications for your app
2. The token may be invalid
3. User may not be connected

The documentation excerpt is ***"Remember that delivery of notifications is “best effort” and is not guaranteed.***"